# android button doesn't work

Tags: android, button

I've searched a lot of posts here, but the solutions looked the same as my code and it doesn't work. This code is inside a method in a fragment. The strange thing is that i have the exactly same code in another fragment and it works.

```
final Button acceptButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_accept);
acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Accept");
                // SOME OTHER STUFF
            }
}
```

The relevant code that work is exactly the same. It just changes the id that i look for the button. The thing is that it doesn't get into de listener. I'll post it anyway in case someone finds it useful.

```
final Button acceptButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_add);
acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Add");
                // SOME OTHER STUFF
}
```

Both codes are inside different fragments. Both codes are written inside the overrided `onOptionsItemSelected`. Except for the listener in the case i have trouble, it gets in.

I'll post the exact code of the onOptionItemSelected that doesn't work in case i'm missing something more trivial.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
            final LinearLayout deletePopup = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.delete_verification);
            deletePopup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Button acceptButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_accept);
            final Button cancelButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Delete button clicked");
            acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Accept delete");
                    deletePopup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    delete(getId().intValue());
                    getActivity().finish();
//                    load();
                }
            });
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Cancel delete");
                    deletePopup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post that fragment code where its working fine

Comment: Please, Can you post more code? This is an activity or not?

Answer (score 0):

replace

> final Button acceptButton = (Button)
>   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_accept);

with

> final Button acceptButton =  (Button)***view***.findViewById(R.id.button_accept);

Here view is the fragment layout

Answer (score 0):

Try to inflate the `View` which contains your `Button` and then, use this `View`
to find the id of your `Button` like :

```
final Button acceptButton = (Button)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.button_accept);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. I was missing the z-axis. I called

`deletePopup.bringToFront();` and i solved it

Thanks to everyone